# SQL Server : select the total sum of all the models from each agency and select the count of each model

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the total sum of all the models from each agency and select the count of each model.

We have different tables in a database of cars agency, I have the next query:

```
SELECT distinct (c.check) ,cm.description as agency, cms.description as model, co.result
FROM check c 
INNER JOIN check_obd co on c.idcheck=co.idcheck
INNER JOIN vehicular_census vc on vc.idvehicularcensus = c.idvehicularcensus
LEFT JOIN cat_mark cm on vc.idmark=cm.key
LEFT JOIN cat_mark_submark cms on vc.idmark_submark=cms.idmark_submark
WHERE  c.operation_status=5
```

This query is not ideal as it produces:

[image: Before]

I would like the result to look like this:

[image: After]

How can I modify the above query to get my desired result?

Comment: What you're looking for can be achieved by a simple GROUP BY statement with counts. e.g. `SELECT cm.description AS agency, COUNT(cms.description) OVER (PARTITION BY cm.description) AS total, cms.description AS model, COUNT(*) AS quantity FROM <insert my tables> GROUP BY cm.description, cms.description`... To get that specific output, you'd probably need to assign a row number (partitioned by agency) to the result set and make the agency/total null if row number isn't 1.

Comment: Hi ZLK I rn the next query: Hi ZLK I run the next query:                         SELECT distinct cm.description as agency,count(cm.description) 
OVER (PARTITION BY cm.descripcion) as total,
cms.description as model, count(cms.description)
OVER (PARTITION BY cms.description) as subtotal
FROM check c 
INNER JOIN check_obd co on c.idcheck=co.idcheck
INNER JOIN vehicular_census vc on vc.idvehicularcensus = c.idvehicularcensus
LEFT JOIN cat_mark cm on vc.idmark=cm.key
LEFT JOIN cat_mark_submark cms on vc.idmark_submark=cms.idmark_submark
WHERE  c.operation_status=5 order by cm.description

Comment: The previous query get me this result : https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ak2f8MCNYPvQgyI_Rd8lLKP15oB8                                          ***** How i can erase the various total result to get only one total for each agency? , thanks :9

Comment: To remove the excess stuff, you'll want to add a row_number to each row and put it in a subquery... I'll write out an example of how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could "remove" the excess stuff (using the current query you provided):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN colagency ELSE '' END) agency
     , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CAST(total AS VARCHAR(255)) ELSE '' END) total
     , model
     , subtotal
FROM (SELECT distinct cm.description as colagency
     , count(cm.description) OVER (PARTITION BY cm.descripcion) as total
     , cms.description as model
     , count(cms.description) OVER (PARTITION BY cms.description) as subtotal
     , row_number() over (partition by cm.description order by cms.description) rn
FROM check c 
INNER JOIN check_obd co on c.idcheck=co.idcheck 
INNER JOIN vehicular_census vc on vc.idvehicularcensus = c.idvehicularcensus 
LEFT JOIN cat_mark cm on vc.idmark=cm.key 
LEFT JOIN cat_mark_submark cms on vc.idmark_submark=cms.idmark_submark 
WHERE c.operation_status=5) T
GROUP BY colagency, model, subtotal
ORDER BY colagency
```

Essentially it's encasing your current query in a subquery with a row_number() function, and then making anything that isn't the first row for an "agency" blank.

Comment: Hi ZLK i run the query provided and it appears to erase all the repeated vales but, the results of the totals for each agency are printed to the last position  like the next image:   https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ak2f8MCNYPvQgyQ2JIQcASqMCB3T, how can i put each total at the start of each submodel like the image 2 shown in the main question? :), btw thanks a lot for the time invested

Comment: OK. I *believe* the above edit has fixed the issue. Essentially reworking the outer query (with a minor edit to the inner query) so that you get the proper grouping and the results you expect.

Comment: I guess so, ill try some more querys to get the expected result :) and ill post it :) thanks really a lot :)